# "Лимит на количество" или "лимит количества"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть фраза:

> Превышен лимит, определяющий максимально количество неудачных попыток.

Эту фразу необходимо значительно сократить, но так, чтобы оба ключевых слова "лимит" и "количество" обязательно остались.

Платежная система предлагает вариант:

> Превышен лимит на количество неудачных попыток.

Мне такой вариант согласования кажется не очень удачным, я бы предпочел:

> Превышен лимит количества неудачных попыток.

Хотя и этот вариант звучит далеко не идеально.
Поиск в Интернете показывает, что **оба** варианта вполне успешно применяются на сайтах вполне солидных финансовых организаций.

Но как все-так грамотнее: "лимит на количество" или "лимит количества"? Или может быть какой-то третий вариант?

Comment: Второй вариант более тяжеловесный на слух. Но, пожалуй, более точный в выражении смысла. Оба варианта грамматически корректны. Первый вариант допускает больше вольности в трактовке смысла, но это никак не ощущается на слух и не ведет к недоразумениям.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, в этой фразе слово "*количество*" лишнее. Лимит уже подразумевает ограничение количества. Слово "*неудачных*" тоже можно было бы исключить, поскольку повтор попыток означает, что предыдущие были неудачными: "*Превышен лимит попыток*". Но, понимая, что это слово все же может быть важным для вас в данном контексте, я бы предложила такой вариант: "*Превышен лимит неудачных попыток*".

Comment: Мне тоже показалось, что "количество" там лишнее. А вот с "на" без него уже не обойтись.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что с "на" нужно обязательно использовать слово "количество"? "Лимит на количество попыток"? Стилистически не очень. Лучше все же "лимит попыток".

Comment: Ну да. Ведь не скажешь "лимит на (неудачные) попытки". А вот "лимит запросов" (без "количества") уже не звучит.

Comment: Проблема в том, что там целый набор этих лимитов. Лимитируется количество неудачных попыток, количество успешных транзакций, количество попыток (сумма удачных транзакций и неудачных попыток), также лимитируется сумма удачных транзакций (поэтому важно наличие слова "количество" в количественных лимитах, чтобы четко отделять их от лимитов сумм (также есть еще частотные лимиты). Также есть ряд нюансов, касающихся поиска названий. Именно поэтому я акцентировал внимание в вопросе на то, что  оба ключевых слова "лимит" и "количество" необходимо обязательно оставить.

Answer (score 1):

Исходная фраза не очень грамотна. Мне не нравится сочетание "*лимит, определяющий*" (потому что будто даётся определение понятию "лимит", а желательно — указать, что он делает). Улучшить её можно так (при этом она заметно сокращается):
*Превышен лимит, ограничивающий количество попыток.*

Согласен, что и этот вариант (с "*лимит количества*") звучит далеко не идеально (как и тот). В таких случаях обычно пишут как-то так: *Попытки ввода ... исчерпаны.*

Мне кажется, что предлог "на" перешёл с "*установлен лимит на*" — и что употреблять его лучше с такими глаголами/причастиями.

Comment: Исходная фраза была "для внутреннего пользования", чтобы просто объяснить суть вопроса. На основании ее было необходимо сделать тот самый краткий вариант, которые уже будет виден публично.

Comment: Можно ещё так: *Превышено допустимое количество неудачных попыток.*

Comment: Там должны быть слова "лимит" и "количество", чтобы отразить слова 'limit' и 'count' из кода ошибки, именно поэтому я акцентировал этот момент в вопросе. По сути, манипулировать можно только склонениями и предлогами. Поэтому задача именно в том, чтобы правильно согласовать "лимит" и "количество".

Comment: Ну тогда считаю, что правильнее "лимит чего-то", а если "на", то с глаголом/причастием — "поставлен/установлен на что-то". Иначе разговорный вариант.

Comment: Я тоже на данный момент склоняюсь к этому варианту. Принимать какой-либо ответ пока не буду, вдруг появятся еще какие-нибудь интересные идеи. Ограничусь данными ранее голосами "за" оба предложенных ответа.